# Create static JPG from Angular implementation of Google Maps

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, pdf

Here is my question, and afterwards I'll give some context.I'll try add as much info here to help.

**Is it possible to render a JPG from a Angular implementation of Google Maps with dynamic waypoints?**

Context:
We currently have an angular implementation of google maps that allows us to turn on and off waypoints from a GUI. Turning off a route, hides that from the map.

There are various settings that can be changed in the GUI that dictates where the waypoints will go and therefore the route.

The purpose or objective outcome is to be able to take a JPG of that map configuration and embed in email, attach, send to customer etc etc

UPDATE: I should note that we have considered building the static map through the API directly by appending waypoints to the URL, however we need to use our custom styled map overlay.

Any help or guidance would be most appreciated.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: This is not related to AngularJS but to creating an image file from the current browser rendering... My suggestion is to create a view using the map logic with your custom overlays and render it using http://wkhtmltopdf.org/ on the server, but first try using the static API instead.

Comment: Thanks coma, I'll look into that, thanks for the direction.